# How can I capture terminal arrow keys in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, escaping, arrow-keys

How can I capture arrow keys in a terminal, without the user having to press "enter" after the arrow key?

Comment: What do you mean in terminal? Are you just in a shell prompt, or are you trying to capture arrow keys in an irb prompt?

Comment: I mean in the mac application "Terminal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the Ruby console libraries [ruby-termios](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-termios)
and [ncurses-ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/ncurses-ruby).