# Creating arrow key navigation in a command line application?

Tags: ruby, shell, menu

I'm trying to dynamically generate a list from file names in a directory using Ruby.

I already have all the code, but my problem is the user interface. In programs such as "testdisk" and "photorec", menu navigation is done via the arrow keys and the enter key alone, without having to type out the name of the option.

Is there a way to reproduce this behavior in a Ruby program?

Comment: You are likely looking for `ncurses` and `curses` libraries. Possibly a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3301777/485864)

Comment: @vgoff They are very similar questions, but the links in the answer to the previous question were discontinued. Can I ask what the difference is between Ncurses and Curses?

Comment: [WikipediA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) likely can answer that question better than I can.

Comment: @vgoff Thank you so much! You were absolutely correct, that is perfect for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I spent a moment and updated the links given in the referred to possible duplicate question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=curses) is a great resource for finding gems that you can use, the link here pointing toward the search for 'curses'.

`ncurses` should work with any ANSI/Posix compliant system.